# What does "IP" mean in military aviation?

Tags: meaning, american-english

In [Catch-22](https://books.google.at/books?id=UJfUAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA64&dq=catch-22+%2B+they+were+at+the+i.++p.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR0Lvv1InhAhUB2aYKHdhjCzwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=catch-22%20%2B%20they%20were%20at%20the%20i.%20%20p.&f=false) I found the mention of the abbreviation "IP":

> One of the surprising things always was the sense of calm and utter silence, broken only by the test rounds fired from the machine guns, by an occasional toneless, terse remark over the intercom, and, at last, by the sobering pronouncement of the bombardier in each plane that they were fully at the **IP** and about to turn toward the target.

What does **IP** mean?

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP) I could not find anything that would make sense in the context

Comment: You may find [this list of US military abbreviations](https://wikileaks.org/wiki/US_Military_Abbreviations) helpful in reading _Catch 22_. I don’t know IP either, but from the context, I would guess the P to stand for _position_. The abbreviation page lists _initial point_ and _instrumentation point_ among the possible meanings of _IP_, which could be what’s intended (though I don’t know what exactly the latter is).

Comment: Perhaps better asked in [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this list](http://www.dreamlandresort.com/info/aviation_glossary.html) of Military Aviation terms:

> IP - Initial Point - the last navigation way point for a strike aircraft before beginning a bomb run. Usually the weapons officer has control of the aircraft from the I.P. to the target

Which does seem to match up to the context of the quote in the question.